# giving another Unicode symbol as output which is not even in my php code

Tags: php, unicode, symbols

my code is not giving desired output as it gives  output those
symbols which is not even in my code

```
 for example 
 2e780048b99d71f45a  //this the input string
 I Ä g Â Æ Ã Ã È Â   //this is the output string what i am getting 
 I Ļ g ¢ Ơ ý Ñ ȟ ¶   // desired output
```

i am encoding-

> 2e  as I
>
> 78  as Ļ
>
> 00  as g
>
> 48  as ¢

and so on....

```
   ` <?php
     $str=file_get_contents("t.txt");

     $tlength = strlen($str)-1;
  for($i2=0;$i2<=$tlength;$i2++)
{
    if($str[$i2]=='2'&&$str[$i2+1]=='e')
      {
         $str[$i2]='I';
        $str[$i2+1]=" ";
        $i2++;
      }
  if($str[$i2]=='7'&&$str[$i2+1]=='8')
     {
        $str[$i2]='Ļ';
        $str[$i2+1]=" ";
         $i2++;
      }
      }
    // and so on for other  input string
// and after all if() part execution, code will execute last part which is given below
 $str= str_replace(' ', "", $str);

  $myfile = fopen("test.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");

  fwrite($myfile, $str);


  fclose($myfile);

   ?>`
```

i am using sublime ide and xammp on windows8.1

i think some special character are more than 8 bit long (may b 16 bit or 32). and at the time of output it takes only 8 bit from that special character which is actuallly more than 8 bit  and print 8 bit value only .is there any way to resolve this?

Comment: My guess is it's an issue with character encoding.

Comment: i think the problem is that system is taking  only 8 bit character .